# Updating chart.js not working after recieved new data from database with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, chart.js

This is my script inside the script where I init the charts

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready( () => {
    setInterval( () => {
    var sensorUpdatedData = new XMLHttpRequest();
    sensorUpdatedData.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if(sensorUpdatedData.readyState === 4) {
        if(sensorUpdatedData.status === 200) {
          console.log("ready");           
          var Data = JSON.parse(sensorUpdatedData.responseText);
          console.log(Data);

          valueTemp = Data.temperature;
          valueHum = Data.humidity;
          valueSmoke = Data.smoke;
          reading_time = Data.reading_time;
          reading_time_hour = Data.reading_time_hour;



          myChartTemp.update();
          myChartHum.update();
          myChartSmoke.update();
          myChartData.update();

        } else {
          alert('Error Code: ' +  sensorUpdatedData.status);
          alert('Error Message: ' + sensorUpdatedData.statusText);
        }
      }
    }
      sensorUpdatedData.open('POST', 'data.php', true);
      sensorUpdatedData.send();
    }, 5000);
  });
```

All the values are updating correctly(I tested with some console.log)

This is how I created one of the charts:

```
var ctxTempChart = document.getElementById("chartLineTemp").getContext("2d");

    var gradientStrokeTempChart = ctxTempChart.createLinearGradient(0, 230, 0, 50);

    gradientStrokeTempChart.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(29,140,248,0.2)');
    gradientStrokeTempChart.addColorStop(0.4, 'rgba(29,140,248,0.0)');
    gradientStrokeTempChart.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(29,140,248,0)'); //blue colors

    var dataTemp = {
      labels: reading_time_hour,
      datasets: [{
        label: "Temperature",
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: gradientStrokeTempChart,
        borderColor: '#1f8ef1',
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderDash: [],
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        pointBackgroundColor: '#1f8ef1',
        pointBorderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#1f8ef1',
        pointBorderWidth: 20,
        pointHoverRadius: 4,
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 15,
        pointRadius: 4,
        data: valueTemp,
      }]
    };

    var myChartTemp = new Chart(ctxTempChart, {
      type: 'line',
      data: dataTemp,
      options: gradientBarChartConfigurationTempSmall

    });
```

**HTML**

```
 <canvas id="chartLineTemp"></canvas>
```

Everything seem to work fine but I don't know how to display the updated data.
The vavalueTemp, valueHum... are declareted globally, at the beggining of the script

**UPDATE**
If I add this:

```
myChartTemp.data.labels = reading_time_hour; 
myChartTemp.data.datasets[0].data = valueTemp; 
window.myChartTemp.update();
```

I got this(with document also): *Cannot read property 'update' of undefined at XMLHttpRequest.sensorUpdatedData.onreadystatechange*

And if I go like this:

```
myChartTemp.data.labels = reading_time_hour;
myChartTemp.data.datasets[0].data = valueTemp;
myChartTemp.update();
```

(without window or document in front)I got ths: *TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object*

Comment: is your `valueTemp` an object? can you show the structure of it?

Comment: That was the problem, I was passing an object and it expected an array. My ```var Data``` is a single JSON object containing multiple JSON objects. After I applied ```valueTemp = JSON.parse(Data.temperature); ```, it returns an array of temperature values, exactly what I needed. Thank you verry much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was passing an object and it expected an array. My `var Data` is a single JSON object containing multiple JSON objects. After I applied `valueTemp = JSON.parse(Data.temperature);` , it returns an array of temperature values, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the update function as a DOM object?

`window.myChartTemp.update();` or 
`document.myChartTemp.update();`

Comment: If I add this: _myChartTemp.data.labels = reading_time_hour;
          myChartTemp.data.datasets[0].data = valueTemp;
          window.myChartTemp.update();_ , I got this(with document also): **Cannot read property 'update' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.sensorUpdatedData.onreadystatechange** and if I go like this : _myChartTemp.data.labels = reading_time_hour;
          myChartTemp.data.datasets[0].data = valueTemp;
          myChartTemp.update();_ (without window or document in front, I got ths: **TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object**

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I have setInterval function and script for dashboard in the same file? https://stackoverflow.com/users/11951277/alexander-riedel

Comment: Does your `console.log(Data);` print an output to the console every five seconds?